# How to save an edited txt file into a new txt file?

Tags: python, save

I am trying to save my output from **x** `.txt` files in only one `.txt` file.
The `.txt` file should look like the output as you can see in the picture [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOf1Z.png).
What this program actually does is read a couple of `.txt` files with tons of data which I filter out using regex.

My source code:

```
import os,glob 
import re 

folder_path =(r"C:\Users\yokay\Desktop\DMS\Messdaten_DMT")
values_re = re.compile(r'\t\d+\t-?\d+,?\d*(\t-?\d+,?\d+){71}')     

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            match = values_re.search(line)
            if match:
                values = match.group(0).split('\t')
                assert values[0] == ''
                values = values[1:]
                print(values)
```

Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: Do not post a picture. Please write your code here and make sure it is formatted and clearly state what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you just need to open a file and write values to it. Try with this. You might need to format (I cannot test since I don't have your text files. I am assuming the output you have in values is correct and keep in mind that this is appending, so if you run more than once you will get duplicates.

```
import os,glob 
import re
folder_path =(r"C:\Users\yokay\Desktop\DMS\Messdaten_DMT") 
values_re = re.compile(r'\t\d+\t-?\d+,?\d*(\t-?\d+,?\d+){71}') 
outF = open("myOutFile.txt", "a")
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as lines:
        for line in lines: 
            match = values_re.search(line)
            if match: 
                values = match.group(0).split('\t') 
                assert values[0] == '' 
                values = values[1:] 
                outF.write(values)
                print(values)
```

Comment: Works fine, i had to add outF.write(str(values)).

The problem i have now is the formatation as u said.

Thanks a lot OsumanAAA !